# using arrays to create a diagonal line of objects using for in loops

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two arrays of points for a diagonal line of objects position and I want x[1] to go with y[1]. This is what I have done

```
for X in x{
for Y in y{

positions.append(CGPoint(x:X,y:Y))

 }
}
```

This doesn't work though because it makes the array[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1), etc...] this makes a grid and what I want is a diagonal line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is

```
for i in 0...4{//or whatever the total amount of numbers are in the array
    positions.append(CGpoint(x[i],y[i]))
}
```

this will pair every x with every y. Sense each point of x is the same as that one in y, you could just have x and do

```
for X in x{
    positions.append(CGPoint(x:X,y:X))
}
```

There is no need to have two arrays of the exact same value

Comment: thank you that worked exactly the way i wanted it to. I will accept your answer as soon as i am allowed

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for i in (0..<x.count) {
   positions.append(CGPoint(x:x[i], y:y[i]))
}
```